# Windows 8 Transparent Avatars?

Tags: windows-8

I was wondering if it is possible to use a transparent image as your account avatar and for the transparency to be shown as it would normally.

For example, I am currently using this image as my Account Avatar, it has a background.
[image]
I then removed the background and was wondering if it is possible to show the transparency, if it doesn't display it by default.
[image]

Although this a small tweak, I would like it to be possible.

Comment: what is the foreground supposed to be transparent to?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

Q: How do you show transparency without a background? A: You Can't, Transparency is all about the background.

What are you intending for the foreground image to be transparent too?

---

**How do you make a .BMP file transparent?**

[Shadow Knows](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090227135909AAb5qHv) answered 6 years ago

> To make a transparent bitmap you must make sure that the bitmap has
>   been converted to Indexed 256 colour. 24bit Bitmaps will not make a
>   transparent image. Make sure that pixel (0,0) in the top left most
>   part of the picture has the colour you want to be transparent.
>
> If you have a background colour that you do not want to be transparent
>   put another colour at pixel (0,0), preferably 1 that doesn't appear in
>   the rest of the image. Some image editors allow you to add a colour to
>   the palette if needed.
>
> In some cases setting colour 0 in the colour index also can help.

Comment: So you're saying that you can't use `.png` transparent images?

Comment: Could you sum up the essentials for those of us who don't want to sit through a youtube video with thumping music, or in case said video goes down?

Comment: Sure... i don't see why i cant

Comment: So transparency won't work if you want to use a transparent image for your login avatar on win8?